# Calculate product of floating point numbers with fixed point arithmetic

Tags: c, fixed-point

I have two jobs to do:

1. I need to store two sensor values in memory (using a FPU)
2. and then calculate the product of those two values without a FPU.

My sensors are:

- Sensor 1 gives values between 0 and 40 with a resolution of 0.2
- Sensor 2 gives values between -10 and 10 with a resolution of 0.1

To store the data in a efficient way, I converted the values to integers by using an offset and a scaling factor

```
uint8 uint_value = (floating_value - offset) / resolution;
```

Sample data:
Sensor 1:

```
Real World Value 0.0 -> uint_value = 0
Real World Value 20.2 -> uint_value = 101
```

Sensor 2:

```
Real World Value -10.0 -> uint_value = 0
Real World Value 0.5 -> uint_value = 105
```

Now I'm having some problems with the second task. I need to calculate the product of those two values without using floating point arithmetic.

How do I do this? I have had a look in fixed point numbers, which offer a possibility to do a multiplication by integer multiplication and shifting.
But I can't seem to figure out how to convert my scaled values to fixed point numbers.

Comment: Please provide some sample data - both before and after converted for storage.

Comment: Aside, For the first step, I would have "rounded" with `value =  lround((floating_value - offset) / resolution);`  Of course `uint8` is not so good with "values between -10 and 30 with a resolution of 0.1".  Try `int16_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Perform integer multiplication and then shift the decimal by the sum of your scales.

Comment: But my scales are not exactly representable in binary fractions.
How do I deal with the offset values?

I have also thought about converting my "manually scaled" values to fixed point numbers in a fixed format like Q8.8, but i havent found out how to do that either

Comment: Your radix is 10 and your exponent is -1, hence the resolution of 10^-1 = .1 so after multiplication, really will have resolution of 10^-2 = .01

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running in to is, basically, that 0.2 and 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. You multiplied one value by 5 and the other by 10. At some point you need to divide their product by 50,  which is not possible via a simple shift. Your calculations will not be exact, regardless of whether you use floating or fixed-point operations. You must ask yourself how much precision you require in the result.

To use fixed-point arithmetic, multiply each sensor value by a power of 2, say 256. Use a **signed** 16-bit variable and don't subtract any offset. The result of this multiplication will have the top 8 bits representing the integer part of the sensor reading and the bottom 8 bits representing an **inexact** fractional part of the sensor reading.

Multiply these two 16 bit values to obtain a signed, 32-bit result. The bottom sixteen bits represent the fractional part of the product. Now you can round or truncate those fractional bits to your desired level of precision. But you can't say your precision will be 0.02 because that's not a rational binary value. Your precision must be of the form 1/2^F where F is the number of fraction bits you retain in the final answer.

Comment: I agree with your assessment. If the offset can be ditched, this is the way to go.